# Pipeline type could not be found (using .Net 4.7.2)

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.7.2

I am currently trying to run a simple PowerShell script through WinForms on Visual Studio 2022, using .Net Framework 4.7.2.  I followed an example I found online, the code shown further below.

I added System.Management.Automation to NuGet Packages, as was recommended but the 'Runspace' type was not recognised.
Following this I read that adding PowerShellStandard.Library to Nuget Packages would allow it to be recognised, and it was.  Unfortunately, the 'Pipeline' type was then not recognised.

I tried to downgrade the System.Management.Automation, but I could not get it to work.  I then created a .Net Core version (.Net 6.0) and the code below worked (after adding System.Managerment.Automation 7.2.7 to Nuget).

Any ideas why Pipeline didn't work on my .Net Framework solution? Thank you in advance for any help!

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CallPowerShellScriptPractice
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnRunScript_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            Command command = new  Command(@"C:\Practice\PowerShellPractice\hello.ps1");
            pipeline.Commands.Add(command);

            pipeline.Invoke();
            runspace.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("PowerShell script being executed..");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of version of the package [System.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation) are compatible with .NET Framework.

If you install this package in a .NET Framework project :

```
dotnet new console --name Demo.Shell --framework netcoreapp3.1 --target-framework-override net472
cd Demo.Shell
dotnet add package System.Management.Automation --version 6.1.6
```

You get the error :

```
...
error: NU1202: Package System.Management.Automation 6.1.6 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2). Package System.Management.Automation 6.1.6 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
error: NU1202: Package System.Management.Automation 6.1.6 is not compatible with net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2) / win7-x86. Package System.Management.Automation 6.1.6 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
error: Package 'System.Management.Automation' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '.\Demo.Shell\Demo.Shell.csproj'.
```

This library can't be installed and its types can't be used.

---

About [PowerShellStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library), it has the types `RunspaceFactory` and `Runspace`, but not `Pipeline`.

However it's a library to develop PowerShell module. I don't think it can be used to execute a script.

---

The only solution I found to execute a PowerShell script from .NET Framework program, it's to use [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) to call PowerShell like :

```cs
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell", "-NoLogo");
processInfo.Arguments = @"C:\t\hello.ps1";
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Data);
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Hi Vernou, sorry for the late reply! but I have tried the above method within a Console Application using .Net Framework and it works! I greatly appreciate your help, thanks again

Just a note for anyone else reading; the console produced an error with running the PowerShell script, so I had to change my execution policy in order to run them:
$ Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope:CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy:Unrestricted
This allows any script to be run using your current user, so please be careful.